# Update Notification not appearing when an update is available

Tags: 11.10, update-manager, notification

I have a laptop and a PC. On the laptop, whenever an update comes it tells me there is an update in two ways. The first one is a red alert/warning icon in the upper panel. The other one is the notification bubble that mentions there is an update and how many updates are available as seen on this image:

[image]

The problem is that on the PC it does not mention any updates, nor does it show a notification bubble saying that I have updates. I have to literally go to the Gear in the top right corner and see if it tells me something like in this image:

[image]

As one can see in this second image there is no red alert/warning that I have updates waiting and there is no bubble telling me that there are updates ready.

How can I add this to the PC so I know when updates are available.

Comment: **Just a Comment:** I think it was designed that way for desktops since the same thing happens to me as well, not sure though. But what I have noticed is, if there are *important security updates* and the system doesn't get updated for a while, the Update Manager automatically pops up upon logging in.

Comment: In the top example, is that a custom red appindicator with the exclamation point? I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get reminder notifications you can customize `ccsm`'s Unity plugin 'Urgent Animation' setting to 'Wiggle', which will periodically bump the icon out from the launcher and wiggle it, grabbing your attention.

[image: ccsm wiggle setting]

Also, whether you do this or not you can look for the update icon on the Unity launcher for information on updates, like in this example where seven updates are available. On my machine, it is only present when there are updates. I believe this is the default configuration.

[image: update icon in launcher]

Last, make sure you have the Update Manager set to:

1. Check for updates daily
2. Download automatically
3. Display other updates immediately

[image]

Comment: In my case there is no update icon in the launcher. I have actually never seen it there unless I open the update manager.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Strange, it should show. I'm adding another image to show updating settings. Can you check your update settings are the same? If not, it may be time for a bug report.

Comment: Strange is this: I had them both on immediately. Did not work and just for the heck of it I change both to weekly and then back to immediately. Now it shows correctly on the launcher. Would be nice to see where in the gconftool (if any) this 2 update notifications change anything. Thanks Tom.