# Is the power-cog supposed to turn blue when updates are available?

Tags: unity

My understanding was that the power-cog was supposed to turn blue when updates are available. But I've noticed that the updates-manager icon appears on the launcher with updates and my power-cog never turns blue. Also the envelope-indicator never turns blue when i have new emails.

Are these bugs? Was I mistaken in expecting this? Is there something I need to do to activate the "blue" functionality?

Using 11.10 with Thunderbird..

Comment: I am not aware of the power cog supposedly turning blue when updates are available. As far as mail, you have to have to have thunderbird open first (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: We need more information.  Which email client are you using?  Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Please note that you have asked two questions. Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Answer (score 2):

No, the power cog stays the same. You will be notified that updates are available by the Update Manager icon appearing in the launcher. If you want to customise it further, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98743/update-notification-not-appearing-when-an-update-is-available).

For the mail icon, William's comment is correct. Thunderbird has to already be running for it to notify you by changing the icon to blue.

Answer (score 1):

The mail icon turns blue only if Thunderbird is open and set up to check for mail automatically.

I do not think that the power icon was intended to turn blue if there are updates. On my system, Ubuntu 11.10, the update notifier icon shows up (red or orange) and after the updates are done, if they require a restart another blue round arrow icon shows up.